# C# get and modify route table

Tags: c#, routetable

I am wondering if there is a way to get, delete, enter new route into IP routing table. Does .net framework have this implemented?
Currently I have this done with Process.Start and "route" command, but I guess this is not the most efficient way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all registered routes in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908957/get-all-registered-routes-in-asp-net-core)