# Get all registered routes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new to .NET Core. I want to get a list of all registered routes in ASP.NET Core. In ASP.NET MVC we had route table in `System.Web.Routing`, is there something equivalent in ASP.NET Core? I want to get the routes list in my Controller Action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of all routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435734/get-list-of-all-routes)

Comment: I don't find my answer there!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I've created the NuGet package "AspNetCore.RouteAnalyzer" that provides a feature to get all route information.

- [NuGet Gallery | AspNetCore.RouteAnalyzer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.RouteAnalyzer) ... Package on NuGet Gallery
- [kobake/AspNetCore.RouteAnalyzer](https://github.com/kobake/AspNetCore.RouteAnalyzer) ... Usage guide

Try it if you'd like.

### Usage

#### Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package AspNetCore.RouteAnalyzer
```

#### Startup.cs

```
using AspNetCore.RouteAnalyzer; // Add
.....
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ....
    services.AddRouteAnalyzer(); // Add
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ....
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRouteAnalyzer("/routes"); // Add
        ....
    });
}
```

#### Browse

Run project and you can access the url `/routes` to view all route information of your project.
[image]

Comment: Tell please, you return type of request(get, post) with routes list. I didn`t find this information

Comment: The NuGet package is not maintained anymore and it is not working with core 2.2 and up. Below answers are much simpller and workd well for both MVC and razor pages.

Comment: Please update more info on how this works for web api projects . and also later versions. The above answer doesn't work for web api projects.

Comment: is there an easy way to use this lib if you do not use `app.UseMvc`?

Comment: Doesn't work, just returns "TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.HttpMethodActionConstraint' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx'."

Answer (score 39):

You can take an [`ActionDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor) collection from [`IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.iactiondescriptorcollectionprovider).
In there, you can see all actions referred to in the project and can take an [`AttributeRouteInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.attributerouteinfo) or [`RouteValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor.routevalues), which contain all information about the routes.

Example:

```
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;

    public class EnvironmentController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;

        public EnvironmentController(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
        {
            _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;
        }

        [HttpGet("routes", Name = "ApiEnvironmentGetAllRoutes")]
        [Produces(typeof(ListResult<RouteModel>))]
        public IActionResult GetAllRoutes()
        {

            var result = new ListResult<RouteModel>();
            var routes = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items.Where(
                ad => ad.AttributeRouteInfo != null).Select(ad => new RouteModel
                {
                    Name = ad.AttributeRouteInfo.Name,
                    Template = ad.AttributeRouteInfo.Template
                }).ToList();
            if (routes != null && routes.Any())
            {
                result.Items = routes;
                result.Success = true;
            }
            return Ok(result);
        }
    }




    internal class RouteModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Template { get; set; }
    }


    internal class ListResult<T>
    {
        public ListResult()
        {
        }

        public List<RouteModel> Items { get; internal set; }
        public bool Success { get; internal set; }
    }
```

Comment: I think there should be an easier way... :( so far, all this asp.net core MVC stuff looks pretty complex to me. Not sure why they did not provide easy transition from traditional MVC...

Comment: @Alexander It may seem a bit complicated but I tried Edgar Mesquita's solution and it works. He included his own classes there which you could replace with Tuple<string, string> to make it simpler.

Comment: Based on your answer, I updated the action to return a HTML response with all the routes and the according controller/actions: https://pastebin.com/WK7GPrQf

Answer (score 22):

You can also use 
`Template = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Template`  value from `ActionDescriptors.Items` array. Here is a full code sample from [there](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6330) :

```
    [Route("monitor")]
    public class MonitorController : Controller {
        private readonly IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider _provider;

        public MonitorController(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider provider) {
          _provider = provider;
        }

        [HttpGet("routes")]
        public IActionResult GetRoutes() {
            var routes = _provider.ActionDescriptors.Items.Select(x => new { 
               Action = x.RouteValues["Action"], 
               Controller = x.RouteValues["Controller"], 
               Name = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Name, 
               Template = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Template 
            }).ToList();
            return Ok(routes);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Consider adding "   .Where(ad => ad.AttributeRouteInfo != null) " before the .Select to avoid null-exceptions.

Comment: My next comment is my overly(?) null-safety-check version (too big to put into one comment)

Comment: var routes = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items
                .Where(ad => ad.AttributeRouteInfo != null)
                .Select(x => new {
                Action = null != x && null != x.RouteValues && null != x.RouteValues["action"] ? x.RouteValues["action"] : "n/a",
                Controller = null != x && null != x.RouteValues && null != x.RouteValues["controller"] ? x.RouteValues["controller"] : "n/a",
                Name = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Name ?? "n/a",
                Template = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Template ?? "n/a"
            }).ToList();

Comment: You can get typed access to Controller-releted information by casting to `ControllerActionDescriptor`. For example, if you are only interested in controller actions, do: `actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()` (To get a list that only includes actions defined in controllers and where the items have typed properties like, for example, `ControllerTypeInfo`.)

Answer (score 8):

### List routes using ActionDescriptor WITH http method (get,post etc)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionConstraints;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;

[Route("")]
[ApiController]
public class RootController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;

    public RootController(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
    {
        _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;
    }

    public RootResultModel Get()
    {
        var routes = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items.Where(
            ad => ad.AttributeRouteInfo != null).Select(ad => new RouteModel
        {
            Name = ad.AttributeRouteInfo.Template,
            Method = ad.ActionConstraints?.OfType<HttpMethodActionConstraint>().FirstOrDefault()?.HttpMethods.First(),
            }).ToList();

        var res = new RootResultModel
        {
            Routes = routes
        };

        return res;
    }
}

internal class RouteModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Template { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
}

internal class RootResultModel
{
    public List<RouteModel> Routes { get; set; }
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPigv.png)

Comment: Can you share RouteModel and RootResultModel too?

Comment: @Rentering.com Im afraid the code has gone missing, but I think RouteModel.Name/Method = String and rootResultModel.Routes = RouteModel []

Answer (score 7):

Using [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) did the trick for me.

You just need to use AttributeRouting on controllers you want to list (and on their actions)

Answer (score 5):

Please up-vote OTHER answers before mine.

My contribution is taking several of the answers and merging them into one.

I also contributed:

Use of anonymous-type (to avoid strong-objects) (99.9% of the time, I prefer strongly-typed-objects, but this is a purely friendly-informational information).

null check safety (it might be overkill, but i'd prefer overkill to a ArgumentNullException when I'm trying to figure something out).

I included "using" statements.  #gasp

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionConstraints;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;

namespace My.WebApiProject.Controllers
{
    public class EnvironmentController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;

        public EnvironmentController(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
        {
            _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;
        }

        [HttpGet("routes", Name = "ApiEnvironmentGetAllRoutes")]
        public IActionResult GetAllRoutes()
        {
            /* intentional use of var/anonymous class since this method is purely informational */
            var routes = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items
                .Where(ad => ad.AttributeRouteInfo != null)
                .Select(x => new {
                Action = null != x && null != x.RouteValues && null != x.RouteValues["action"] ? x.RouteValues["action"] : "n/a",
                Controller = null != x && null != x.RouteValues && null != x.RouteValues["controller"] ? x.RouteValues["controller"] : "n/a",
                Name = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Name ?? "n/a",
                Template = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Template ?? "n/a",
                Method = x.ActionConstraints?.OfType<HttpMethodActionConstraint>().FirstOrDefault()?.HttpMethods.First()
                }).ToList();
            return Ok(routes);
        }
    }
}
```

> "Name = x.AttributeRouteInfo.Name ?? "n/a",

the "n/a" actually shows up from time to time.

This below optional package may be required.

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
```

Answer (score 5):

The collection of routes can be listed by retrieving the collection of EndpointDataSource from DI.

Example for .NET 6:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapGet("/debug/routes", (IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointSources) =>
        string.Join("\n", endpointSources.SelectMany(source => source.Endpoints)));
}

app.Run();
```

[image]

For more details, go [here](https://www.meziantou.net/list-all-routes-in-an-asp-net-core-application.htm)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use MVC call `GetRouteData().Routers.OfType<RouteCollection>().First()` for access to `RouteCollection`:

```
app.UseRouter(r => {
    r.MapGet("getroutes", async context => {
        var routes = context.GetRouteData().Routers.OfType<RouteCollection>().First();
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Total number of routes: " + routes.Count.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        for (int i = 0; i < routes.Count; i++)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(routes[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }               
    });
    // ...
    // other routes
});
```

Make sure to call `GetRouteData()` inside route handler otherwise it returns null.

Comment: In an asp.net core razor page application what is considered "inside the route handler"? after adding the suggested block of code to my startup where can I read the routes written to the context?

Answer (score 2):

I did also using *IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider* getting the information from the `RouteValues`.

```
var routes = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items
    .Select(ad => new
    {
        Action = ad.RouteValues["action"],
        Controller = ad.RouteValues["controller"]
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can inject that on your constructor of your controller

```
IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointSources
```

Then it contains all of mapped routes.

Comment: This was the answer. Upvoted. (Confirmed to work on .Net Core 8 Minimal API)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a router of type `RouteCollection`.  To get all routes of that type you should be able to call `.All()` on routers of type `RouteCollection`.

Example: 
`var routes = RouteData.Routers.OfType<RouteCollection>().All();`

Credit to: 
https://rimdev.io/get-registered-routes-from-an-asp.net-mvc-core-application/

Refer to above article if `.All()` doesn't work.

Comment: This does not work and the provided link does not use .All() or provide the source code.