# Excluding a class as a Controller in convention driven development?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In our project I recently [dumped a list of routes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43443712/306036) to controllers in order to learn a new asp.net project that I recently joined the team of.

However, they have a class used as an attribute in a namespace that is being picked up by asp.net as a controller class, which is registering 'null' / empty routes in the dump, named `GenericController`.

Is there a way to mark this class using attributes (Similar to marking methods using `[NonAction]`) as 'not a controller?' And if not, what alternatives are there for excluding 'matching by convention' named classes from being controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to mark this class using attributes (Similar to marking methods using [NonAction]) as 'not a controller?'

1. There's a built-in [`[NonControllerAttribute]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.noncontrollerattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1).
2. Also, you can make your class a nested class, an abstract class, an internal class, a generic class , etc to avoid picking it as a Controller.

Fore more details, see [Source Code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a49e084c1515dfaa16de8d7d4b0c00190587ad87/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Controllers/ControllerFeatureProvider.cs#L65)

Comment: Will I run into issues with the 'derived types' if our 'genericController' attribute is applied to other controllers that we wish to be registered?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach As far as I know, the `[NonController]` attribute is only a marker attribute that indicates that class should not be be considered as a controller. It won't influence others. So IMO, it shouldn't result in that issue.