# Get all registered routes in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to debug an issue with routes where I'm not sure what url an external app has to hit to trigger my controllers correctly. I just want to print them all out.

I found [Get all registered routes in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908957/get-all-registered-routes-in-asp-net-core) but none of the answers seem to work in Asp.net Core 3.0

I also found https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.RouteAnalyzer, but it's for Core 2.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I just want to print them all out.

So, I guess this is for debugging purposes?

In that case, this will get you started:

```cs
public HomeController(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider provider)
{
    this.provider = provider;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var urls = this.provider.ActionDescriptors.Items
        .Select(descriptor => '/' + string.Join('/', descriptor.RouteValues.Values
                                                                        .Where(v => v != null)
                                                                        .Select(c => c.ToLower())
                                                                        .Reverse()))
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();

    return Ok(urls);
}
```

This will return response in the following format:

```
[
    "/post/delete",
    "/users/index/administration",
    "/users/details/administration",
]
```

If you need more information, the `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` has plenty of it.

Comment: I'd like to confirm that this picks up Razor Pages as well as MVC routes. Also, I don't know how, but I get // in my urls for Areas. So I added a `.Replace("//","/")` to remove them.

Comment: It's not working correctly with `[HttpGet("custom")]`

Comment: @Parsa_Gholipour It was alright 2 years ago, can you tell me what version you are using?

Comment: @edo.n .net 6 and .net core 3