# How can I list endpoints for an ASP.NET Core webservice?

Tags: asp.net-core, ip-address

## Context

I need to find a way for my application to broadcast it's binding addresses through UDP without using `IServerAddressesFeature`.

I found a way to get my broadcast service running despite `BackgroundService` implementations launching before the routing is happening, but for some reason whenever i deploy my application `IServerAddressesFeature` will no longer provide me with addresses, while it reports the correct addresses at debug time.

### Question

Is there some configuration option I can use to just parse the url's from there and skip past diagnosing the reason why the feature works at debug time, but not at deploy time?

### Regarding potential answer

If you have a hunch why it won't work at deploy time feel free to let me know - I gave up on doing this through `IServerAddressesFeature` at this point and a configuration parsed approach would be good enough for me too.

#### Current implementation

Startup.ConfigureServices

```
... lots of configuration
applicationStateTransmitter.NotifyConfigurationDone();
applicationStateTransmitter.NotifyBindingAddressesAvailable(app.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses);
... end of ConfigureServices
```

My service class used to bypass restrictions of the `BackgroundWorker`:

```
public class ApplicationStateTransmitter
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource _configurationDone;
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<ICollection<string>> _bindingAddressesAvailable;

    public ApplicationStateTransmitter()
    {
        _configurationDone = new TaskCompletionSource(null);
        _bindingAddressesAvailable = new TaskCompletionSource<ICollection<string>>(null);
    }

    public Task ConfigurationDone => _configurationDone.Task;

    public void NotifyConfigurationDone() => _configurationDone.SetResult();

    public Task<ICollection<string>> BindingAddressesAvailable => _bindingAddressesAvailable.Task;

    public void NotifyBindingAddressesAvailable(ICollection<string> values) => _bindingAddressesAvailable.SetResult(values);
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908957/get-all-registered-routes-in-asp-net-core) stackoverflow post might help you.

Comment: @TharinduSK sadly no - i know how to get routes, i need the ip endpoints