# Areas do not work when migrating an Angular app to NET 6

Tags: c#, angular, routes, .net-6.0

I have an .NET Core 5 with Angular app and I have my controllers grouped in areas. I made the app using NET Core 1 and have successfully migrated it up to 5 without any problems, but migrating it to NET 6 gives me a 404 errors when I make API calls.

My current NET 5 setup looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]    
[Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]")]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
}

[Area("Home")]
public abstract class HomeController : BaseController
{
}

public class AccountController : HomeController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething()
    {
}
```

I created a new project in VS2022, copied everything, made the changes in `Program.cs` and changed `BaseController` to inherit `ControllerBase`.

The angular app works OK, but all my API calls return 404.

I didn't even have this in the NET 5 app, but I added it now just in case:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name : "areas",
            pattern : "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );
    });
```

but still no luck.

EDIT:

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46019311) answer, I listed all the routes and do get this:

```
{area: 'Home', controller: 'Account', action: 'GetSomething', name: null, template: 'Home/Account/GetSomething'}
```

and I still have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't have to copy *anything*. Just change the target from `net5.0` to `net6.0`. You don't need to change the base class. `ControllerBase` works the same way it did in .NET 5 - it's the common base class for API and MVC controllers and doesn't contain any of the view-related members like `View()` and `TempData`

Comment: Changing the target framework works, but using Areas in the new NET 6 project template doesn't. That was my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the proxy you have to list all the areas `PROXY_CONFIG` in `proxy.conf.js`. Add the area, or if you're using controllers, the controller names to the `context` property, eg:

```
context: ['/AdminApi', '/HomeApi' ... ]
```

Or, as a workaround, add `/Api` before all your calls and then have just that in the proxy settings

Comment: Can you give an example code?

Comment: I added some more info to the answer